# Change text color on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts, colors

I have a font problem. I have to change the font color on mobile devices but I am unable to do this. Do you know how I can do this?

Update: I want a different color for mobile devices than desktops and laptops.

Comment: Does the CSS `color` property not work?  What's your current code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove clutter that is not related to your question and to make the text a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Use CSS Media queries

   ```
   @media screen and (max-width: 400px){
       p {
           color: red;
       }
   }
   ```

   NOTE: You can choose & specify the max-width & styles specific to the max-width yourself.
2. Use jQuery to detect mobile devices & change the color of specific elements.

   ```
   if ($(window).width() < 400) {
        $('element').css( "color", "red" );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about this one!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to detect a mobile device is to know its width and use the corresponding media query to catch it.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/